# Android Insufficient memory with simplest code

Tags: android, opencv

I have some simple code to zoom an image in Android using OpenCV, but it causes an insufficient memory error.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Size original = inputFrame.rgba().size();
    int offx =(int)( 0.01*(currentZoomValue) * original.width);
    int offy =(int)( 0.01*(currentZoomValue) * original.height);
    croped = inputFrame.rgba().submat(offy,(int)(original.height-offy),offx,(int)(original.width-offx));
    inputFrame.rgba().release();
    Imgproc.resize(croped,croped,original);
    return croped;
}
```

"currentZoomValue" and "croped" are my global variables.  I cannot release any variable.

**EDIT 1:**
Logcat showed me this error:

```
    11-08 12:12:07.117 1824-1923/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 8294400 bytes) in void* cv::OutOfMemoryError(size_t), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 52
11-08 12:12:07.117 1824-1923/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in void cv::Mat::create(int, const int*, int), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 424
11-08 12:12:07.127 1824-1923/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/org.opencv.imgproc: imgproc::resize_11() caught cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:424: error: (-215) u != 0 in function void cv::Mat::create(int, const int*, int)
11-08 12:12:07.127 1824-1923/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-63756
                                                                            Process: com.example.salman.opencvtmp, PID: 1824
                                                                            CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:424: error: (-215) u != 0 in function void cv::Mat::create(int, const int*, int)
                                                                            ]
                                                                                at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.resize_1(Native Method)
                                                                                at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.resize(Imgproc.java:2716)
                                                                                at com.example.salman.opencvtmp.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                                                at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:391)
                                                                                at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:350)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-08 12:12:07.177 1824-1824/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/TMP: Zoom value: 47.370927734375
11-08 12:12:07.197 1824-1824/com.example.salman.opencvtmp E/TMP: Zoom value: 47.370927734375
```

Comment: Can you `Debug` the code to know exactly where the code is breaking ?

Comment: updated my question, added logcat output. It breaks when I resize it.

Comment: What is the output resize size `original` ?